# MVC ASP .NET troubleshooting session timeout with Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, global-asax

I’ve build a MVC  based .Net application which has Windows Authentication and has a requirement of redirecting to Session time out page if the user leaves the screen idle for 15 minutes continuously. For this I’m using InProc session mode set to 15 minutes. The session Timeout page has a link to go to Home page of website. There is also a session timeout warning pop out which comes 5 minute before the session timeout. This pop out has option to extend the session and terminate the session and redirect to session timeout.

Issues:

1) When I’m terminating the session using pop out message button and redirecting to sessionTimeout ActionResult, and clearing the session using RemoveALL() and logging the same using Log4Net. But after this if I click on home page button, The session_start method in global.asax is not getting called again.

2) Whenever the session timeout is occurring by itself after 15 minutes then only Session_End is getting called in Global.asax. But after this the control is again going in Session_Start method to navigate to the SessionTimeout page. This is not the expected behavior.

I’m using Javascript to redirect to session timeout page.

Expected o/p -> if session timeout happens by click of button in pop out message, The Session_End should be called. And on click of Homepage link a new session should be generated.

**Can anyone please suggest how should I implement the above scenario.**

Comment: Session. Abandon(), Session.Clear()?

Comment: Hi lrb, I have tried those too. The behavior is the same.